# Creating controller-less route in Symfony

Tags: symfony4

I have an API built in Symfony, which doesn't have anything mapped to 'GET /', however this causes reporting errors since a 404 is being returned when you try to access it, however there is intentionally nothing mapped there.

Routing is done through annotations in the controller classes but I was wondering if I could do something in the config/routes.yaml to simply return a 200 without needing to create a controller to handle the this.

This controller will resolve the issue:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(methods={"GET"}, path="/")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return new Response();
    }
}
```

But I feel that it's just clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way that I can see, is that you can use a `TemplateController`, like this:

```
# config/routes.yaml
index_page:
    path:          /
    controller:    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController
    defaults:
        # the path of the template to render
        template:  'index.html.twig'
```

and put something simple to `templates/index.html.twig` file or just make it empty.

But in any case you need something to specify content that would be returned on `/` route.

Reference: [symfony's doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#templates-render-from-route) (you can find there options for caching your empty page ;))

Comment: Thanks :). Guess have to have 'clutter' somewhere to resolve this but this is still out of the way since we're not actually using any templates.

Comment: in that case I would go with an empty controller, the way you purposed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a 200 OK, how about doing a redirect to the endpoint you mentioned?

```
homepage:
    path: /
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::urlRedirectAction
    defaults:
        path: /app
        permanent: true
```

Comment: Just had a go but it's giving a 404. Should've made it more clear that there is no endpoint on that route but this is intentional.

Comment: @CaiusEhmke what is giving you a 404? The request to "/" or the redirected request to "/app"? You need to update the path attribute to match your API end-point.

Comment: Ah there's nothing in /app either, it's an API only and there's nothing on the "/" endpoint. NewRelic doesn't seem to like this and is complaining that there is nothing on that route so essentially it's just to shut up the reporting :D. But I was hoping to do so without adding clutter classes.